# Edit Javascript and affect timer on HTML page in runtime

Tags: javascript

I am trying to skip timer placed on an HTLM page. Javascript for the TIMER is below:

```
var t = 60;
var decr = 1;
var handle = null;
var e = null;
function startTimer() {
    if(!e) e = document.getElementById("time");
    e.innerHTML = t;
    handle = setInterval(function() {
        if(t == 0) {
            clearInterval(handle);
            var answer = confirm("Yes/No?")
            if (answer){
                alert("You Clicked Yes!")
                window.location = "https://twitter.com/";
            }
            else{
                alert("You Clicked No!")
            }
        }
        else {
            t -= decr;
            e.innerHTML = t;
        }
    }, decr * 1000);
}
window.onload = startTimer;
```

What I want is to change the TIMER to 10 seconds as soon as the page gets loaded.
I tried to enter the following code in browser location bar:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "10";
```

But I'm not getting into it. What'll be the proper way to do it?

Comment: Why not just make it 10 seconds in the first place?

Comment: @JLRishe Actually, its not my page. That's why I want to skip the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the console (development tools). If you are using chrome, press F12, then press console and insert the command

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "10";
```

or

```
document.getElementById('time').value = "10";
```

and then press enter.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I just got that. Actually what it does if it have any value in var e then don't need to get the value of id='time'. Now I just change value of the var t and it works. Thanks again

Comment: Another question. Is there any way that this piece of code executes automatically when a specific page loads i.e. example.com/view.php

Comment: As you said, this is another question, and it's completely different from the previous one. Please open a new thread. If my answer helped you can mark it, or you can give your answer and accept it. But you have to close this thread and open a new one.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll do it. I just thought to save a thread. Anyway, silly me.

Comment: It's a perfectly logic idea, but, it's a good question and it will be lost if it gets answered in the comments.